How do I make a custom video section for Shopify
How can I create a Video section that will work identically like the Image picker section. I don't want to grab videos from youtube, or have them play from vimeo or youtube. I've tried to use the video tag as well as Iframe but both don't work, either showing that file format isn't valid, or that the video can't be played.
            <video width="100%" height="500" controls>
                <source src="{{ section.settings.vid}} " type="link video">
            </video>

This is my code for the current video player, and it is showing the video box and showing that I can upload a video, but when I press play nothing happens, I assume it is the file type in the code, but I am trying to avoid having to restrict the videos we play to a certain file type, is there a way to have it automatically pickup the file type or maybe where it doesn't require it at all?
